# What are the distinctions between 大概 and 大约？

Tags: usage

Both have come up in the course of learning HSK vocabulary, and the dictionary definitions and usage examples I've found for each seem to have a good deal of overlap. Where should they be used, and what differentiates the two?

Comment: HSK＂汉语水平考试词典＂ **大概**  （形）［联合］［义１］（１）估计；可能（general idea;broad outline;probably);从这里到火车站，～有半个小时的路程。（２）模糊而简略（general；rough）：对故乡，我只有个～的印象｜这只是个～的计划，很不具体。 **大约**  （副）［偏正］［义１］（１）表示可能性较大（probably）：他～是看电影了。（２）表示估计的数目不十分精确（approximately；about）：每天～有十几万游客。also see   **previous Q**    https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/6719/what-does-%e5%a4%a7%e6%a6%82-mean-are-there-any-words-with-the-same-meaning/6724#6724，  **jukuu**   :１００ samples for each，

Comment: only 大概 can be used as attributive adjective (see comment #1,大概 (2))

Comment: ＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂大概（副；形；名）／大约（副）／大致（副；形）  **［相同］**  都是副词，作状语。表示对数量的估计时可以互换，＂大概＂多用于口语，＂大约＂多用于书面语，＂大致＂较少用：（１）从百货大楼到电影院大概要走１５分钟的路。（大概✓大致✓）（２）来回机票大约需要４０００元人民币。（大概✓大致✓）（３）这家医院每天大致有六七百人来看病。（大概✓大约✓）  **［不同］１。**  ＂大概、大约＂还可以用于对情况的推测，表示有很大的可能性，＂大概＂更常用；＂大致＂没有这种用法：
（１）他今天没有出席会议，大概有更重要的事情吧。（大约✓大致✗）（２）下这么大的雨，估计今天的活动大概会取消。（大约✓大致✗）（３）张明一副心事重重的样子，大概遇上了什么烦心事吧。（大约✓大致✗）（４）他没在办公室，大概是去银行了。（大约✓大致✗）（５）看样子他大概是外地人。（大约✓大致✗）（６）这些事情大概明天也做不完。（大约✓大致✗）  **２。**  ＂大致（上）＂主要表示＂就主要方面、基本的情形来说＂，相当于＂基本上、大体上＂，作状语；＂大约、大概＂无此用法：（１）开学前的准备工作大致是这样安排的。（大概✗大约✗）（２）这个方案大致包括四大部分。（大概✗大约✗）（３）这两个词的意思大致相同，但有一些小的差异。（大概✗大约✗）（４）这篇文章，我大致（上）能看懂。（大概✗大约✗）

Comment: （５）中国的方言很复杂，大致（上）可分为七个方言区。（大概✗大约✗） **３.**   ＂大概、大致＂还有形容词的用法，意思是＂概括的，粗略的＂，可以作定语、状语：＂大约＂不能这样用：（１）我只知道他们家大概的位置。（大致✓大约✗）（２）我没有认真看，所以只记得大概的内容。（大致✓大约✗）（３）我在那个地方只待了几天，现在只有一点大概的印象。（大致✓大约✗）（４）请你大致介绍一下你们国家的情况。（大概✓大约✗）（５）他记性很好，大致听了一遍就已经记得了。（大概✓大约✗） **4.**  ＂大概＂还可以作名词，表示基本的、粗略的内容：（１）很多生词我都没学过，所以只听懂个大概。（大约✗大致✗）（２）十年前的事情，他现在还能记得个大概就已经很不错了。（大约✗大致✗）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

大概 is more general

大約 is more narrow. Specifically be used to express estimation of numbers

Both 大概 and 大約 can mean "approximately"

"There are **approximately** fifty people" can be translated as "**大概**有五十人" or "**大約**有五十人"

More example:

大概二十英尺 / 大約二十英尺 (about 20 feet)

大概四十岁 / 大約四十岁 (about 40 years old)

大概三年/ 大約三年 (about 3 years)

However, 大概 also means "probably" and "roughly"

You can say 他**大概**不会来了 (He **probably** won't come), but you cannot say 他大約不会来了 (He approximately won't come)

You can also say "**大概**說明一下" (**roughly** explain a little), but you cannot say "大約說明一下" (approximately explain a little)

> Whenever numbers are involved, you can safely use either 大約 or 大概 for "approximately"

Comment: Actually it won't be an error to say "他大约不会来了". E.g 孔乙己大约的确死了

Comment: most modern Chinese say 大概 for "probably"